How can I write an apple script that moves the mouse to a certain position after being idle?
I was searching for a way to move the mouse after some time of inactivity on a MacBook, and due to some constrains, the idle setting in the OS are not accessible, nor are some software that move the mouse.

After hours of trying, I managed to get a working piece of code that:

shall be executed using osascript
needs cliclick to be installed (can be installed using brew)

set initialPosition to {10, 300}
set moveDistance to 10
set idleThreshold to 60 -- Idle threshold in seconds

set previousPosition to missing value
set idleTime to 0

-- Function to get the current mouse position using cliclick
on getMousePosition()
    set mousePosition to {}
    try
        set mousePosition to (do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick p")
        set {mouseX, mouseY} to text items of mousePosition
        return {mouseX as integer, mouseY as integer}
    on error errMsg
        return missing value
    end try
end getMousePosition

repeat
    set currentMousePosition to getMousePosition()
    
    if currentMousePosition is not equal to previousPosition then
        set idleTime to 0
        set previousPosition to currentMousePosition
    else
        set idleTime to idleTime + 5 -- Increment idle time by the delay value
    end if
    
    if idleTime > idleThreshold then
        set currentX to item 1 of initialPosition
        set currentY to item 2 of initialPosition
        
        -- Move mouse up by 10 pixels
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick m:" & currentX & "," & (currentY + moveDistance)
        delay 1 -- Adjust delay as needed
        
        -- Move mouse down by 10 pixels
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick m:" & currentX & "," & (currentY - moveDistance)
        delay 1 -- Adjust delay as needed
        
        -- Reset idle time
        set idleTime to 0
    end if
    
    delay 5 -- Check mouse position every 5 seconds
end repeat


